# How to call to a map or instantiate a map into the main class in flutter?

Tags: flutter, maps

I am working on a program where I have to create 3 pages and 2 of those 3 pages will be using the information within the maps I created. As a result I would like to know if this is can even happen or occur. Along side that how would I call the method class to the main class. As I keep wanting to call it as I would in Java and I know that is not how it is done. Would I call it through the getter and how or would I call the whole class as I have been trying to call the class and it is not working. Along side that I know that in flutter it is usually discourage to do this outside of the class but it would be useful to creating the app pages that I need for my project. Also I have only been programming with flutter for about 2 months.

This is my maps code
import 'dart:collection';

```
class Menu {
  Map<String, double> sandwichMap = {
    "Veggie Melt": 4.50,
    "Crispy Chicken Wrap": 6.95,
    "Italian Meatball Sub": 6.99,
    "Chicken Parm Grinder": 6.59,
    "Grill Cheese": 3.59,
    "Grilled Ham & Cheese": 4.59,
    "Bacon Bagel Melt": 5.29 };

  LinkedHashMap<String, double> getSandwichMap() {
    return this.sandwichMap;
  }
  //check burger prices again
  Map<String, double> burgerMap = {
    "Veggie Burger": 4.99,
    "The Quantum Burger": 7.25,
    "Cafe Melt": 6.59,
    "The Bull Rider": 5.79,
    "Double Cheese Burger": 5.89,
    "Hamburger": 3.99 };

  LinkedHashMap<String, double> getBurgerMap() {
    return this.sandwichMap;
  }

  Map<String, double> otherItemsMap = {
    "Chicken Quesadilla": 6.79,
    "Cheese Quesadilla": 6.29,
    "Chicken Strips":  4.99,
    "Popcorn Chicken": 4.59,
    "Jalapeno Poppers": 3.49 };

  Map<String, double> getOtherItemsMap() {
    return this.sandwichMap;
  }
  Map<String, double> sidesMap = {
    "French Fries": 3.29,
    "Onion Rings": 4.79,
    "Jalapeno Cheese Curds":  4.99,
    "Tater Tots": 3.19,
    "Pretzel Bites": 4.59,
    "Nachos & Cheese":  3.50 };

  Map<String, double> getSidesMap() {
    return this.sandwichMap;
  }
  Map<String, double> pizzaMap = {
    "7-inch Cheese": 4.59,
    "7-inc with topping": 4.99};

  Map<String, double> getPizzaMap() {
    return this.sandwichMap;
  }

}
```

This is my main dart file however I am not finished with it as I have been redone my dart file a handful of times recently I had dropdowns within my main dart file however i removed them to put in a ListView Builder to use the maps within it however I have yet to also figure that out as I don't know how to call to the maps dart file at the moment.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'maps.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  //Always use Stateless first then use stateful or stateless widgets afterward
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //only used at the beginning of the program
      title: 'The Cafe',
      //just a title to the app it does not show for there is nothing telling it to show on the screen
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //takes out the ribbon at the top right corner of the screen and app
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          fontFamily: 'georgia',
          textTheme: TextTheme(headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 100))
        //controls the color of the very top part of the application
      ),
      home: StartPage(),
      //used to connect the Stateless widget to the Stateful widget below
    );
  }
}

  class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartPageState createState() => _StartPageState();
  }
// do not forget the } prior to this comment  if you do it will result in error and the program does not known why either

  class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {



    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('The Campus Cafe'),
          //where the main title is computed to be shown on the screen
          centerTitle: true,
          //centers the title
        ),
        body: Center(
          //This is Header that is after the main Title
          child: Column(

              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[

                //Header Container
                Expanded(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/campus-cafe-logo-350sidebar.png',)
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Our Menu", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder( itemCount: values.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                }
                )
              ]
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
var menu = Menu();
// now you can access its members in your build method:
// menu.getSandwichMap()
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

**There are two more ways you could go:**

Get rid of that Menu class and just expose the Maps directly - in Dart you should avoid having [classes with only static members](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#:%7E:text=AVOID%20defining%20a%20class%20that%20contains%20only%20static%20members.,-Linter%20rule%3A%20avoid_classes_with_only_static_members&text=Other%20classes%20are%20used%20as,class%20just%20to%20define%20something.)

This would look something like this:

map.dart

```dart
const Map<String, double> sandwichMap = {
    "Veggie Melt": 4.50,
    "Crispy Chicken Wrap": 6.95,
    "Italian Meatball Sub": 6.99,
    "Chicken Parm Grinder": 6.59,
    "Grill Cheese": 3.59,
    "Grilled Ham & Cheese": 4.59,
    "Bacon Bagel Melt": 5.29 };
```

```
// you can now access the sandwichMap in any class where you import the file
import 'maps.dart';
// sandwichMap['Bacon Bagel Melt']
```

Both of the above are fine for just playing around - but eventually you want to pass the data through the widget tree using some form of state management. I would recommend to take a look [at the provider example](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifier) - you would do something like this:

```
class Menu extends ChangeNotifier {...}

// and in you main.dart you put a ChangeNotifiverProvider ontop of the widgettree

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => Menu(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```